# Dividing a file by byte count

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, file-io

I am making a file-sharing program, and when I send a file I want to only send 1024 bytes, and then send the next 1024 bytes and so on. I am using scapy and not sockets, so I need to do this manually. How can I divide a file into chunks of 1024 bytes each?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I don't know how to seperate a file into chunks of 1024 bytes each (and less for the last one). I forgot to add this to the question...

Comment: You don't seperate the file, just read 1024 bytes, send them, then read the next 1024 bytes

Comment: How do I read the "next" 1024 bytes? Wouldn't a simple f.read(1024) give me the same 1024 bytes every time?

Comment: No it would not :) as long as you don't close the file between reads

Comment: Thank you very much, I assume I should delete this question as it is useless? I don't know the rules, I'm a newbie here.

Comment: No need to delete, someone alse may have the same question.

Comment: @Fredrik if someone has the same question and looks for an answer, then it's easier if there is an actual answer, instead of trying to read through comment-chat. Comments are what they are, comments, not the actual answer. I'd suggest you or the OP to write an answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write a simple loop:

```
while True:
    block = f.read(1024)
    if not block:
        break
    ... do stuff with block ...
```

Each call to `read` reads data and advances the file position, so you get a new block each time. Alternatively, you can be a little more clever and use two-arg `iter` to make a Python generator that performs the same logic, but works with `for` loops to look a little cleaner:

```
from functools import partial

for block in iter(partial(f.read, 1024), b''):  # Change b'' to '' for text mode file
    ... do stuff with block ...
```